# How to connect to Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect to Firebase using AngularJS.

I know I have to set config info etc. But I don't know where and how.

Where can I put and sync my config in my codes?

Saying my config is like this:

```
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Here are my codes :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test1 with Angular1</title>
    <!-- Angular -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>

    <!-- AngularFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("app",["firebase"]);
        app.controller("myController",["$scope","$firebaseObject",function($scope,$firebaseObject){

            var ref = new Firebase(<url>);
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
        {{ 1+1 }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried adding it to app.run file ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new file(just to keep things clean), call this firebase-config.js
2. Add your config to the file

   ```
   var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBrPs1GLV-0APAs_3PFpvldGbcgE-eVYY",
    authDomain: "letsayone.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://letsayone.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "letsayone.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "175605985282"
   };
   firebase.initializeApp(config);
   ```

3       Now add the js file to your index.html, before your controller codes.

```
....
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="firebase-config.js"></script>
<script>...your controller codes here</script>
```

Note you should be using the latest version of firebase. 3.x.x
[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

Answer (score 1):

Something really confuses me about your question, you are using the 2.0 SDK, and at the same time config files which I think is a 3.0 feature? Correct me if Im wrong!

First of all, try to stay away from the new operator. Its not nice for unit testing.

Its a better way to use constants and angular services.

```
 app
    .constant('firebaseUrl', "https://letsayone.firebaseio.com")
    .service('rootRef', ['firebaseUrl', Firebase])
```

In your controller, you want to inject rootRef

```
app.
    controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'rootRef', function($scope, rootRef){ 
}])
```

Also don't forget to inject firebaseObject or firebaseArray depending on the one you are going to use!

Comment: yep, upgrade guide shows diff btw 2.xx (no config) and 3.xx (config for refs) https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web